# Deep link animsition

Tags: javascript, jquery, animsition

I have integrated "animsition.js" to my website, it work fine but some link don't work in "fade out" effect. I post my code:

```
<nav>


  <div class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right text-left" id="side-menu">
    <!-- LOGO -->
    <a class="animsition-link" href="../../index.html"><img src="../../assets/images/logo/logo_white2.png" alt="logo"></a>
    <a href="#" class="close-menu"><i class="icon ion-ios-close-empty icon-close menu-close-btn text-white"></i></a>


    <div class="top">
      <div class="tr">LANGUAGE_</div>
      <div><a class="animsition-link" href="#"><span class="uns lang">ITALIANO</span></a> <br>
        <a class="animsition-link" href="#"><span class="current lang">ENGLISH</span></a></div>
    </div>



    <ul class="nav navbar-nav container animsition">
      <div class="tr">MENU_</div>

      <li><a class="animsition-link" href="../../index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="expander" href="#">
          <span class="current">PROJECTS LIST</span></a>

        <div class="content">
          <ul role="menu">


            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <span class="rec4">CapozziPaints</span>
              </a>
            </li>



          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>



      <li><a href="../../about.html" class="animsition-link">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">COOKIE POLICY</a></li>




      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <div class="tr">CONTACT ME_</div>
        <li><a href="mailto:info@josedesign.it"><span class="rec3">info@josedesign.it</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="text-white">+39 389.582.3119</span></a></li>

      </ul>

    </ul>
    <!-- End navbar-nav -->
    <p class="copyright grey">2017 JoseDesign.it<br>Proudly designed by Jose.</p>


  </div>
</nav>
```

After my  tag, I have inserted "  ", but some link like "Home", don't make the fade out effect.

The other question is I have to insert a "fadeIn" effect to the "img" tag that I have in this code:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    $.each($('img'), function() {
        if ( $(this).attr('data-src') && $(this).offset().top < ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 100) ) {
            var source = $(this).data('src');
            $(this).attr('src', source);
            $(this).removeAttr('data-src');
        }
    })
})
```

I try several way, the scrolling effect + show image work fine, but the fadeIn effect don't work.

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

solved....

Simply I have change the animsition.js ver. 4.0.2 with vers. 3.4.3....done!

Everything work fine, all the link work fine.

The jquery script (for fadeIn image effect)  doesn't work yet...